# how to sum values only if adjacent cell is filled?

Tags: google-sheets

i have this table:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value | date | creditOrDebit |
| 2 | 10 |  | C |
| 3 | 8 | 03/30/23 | D |
| 4 | 3 | 11/11/23 | C |
| 5 | sumCreditSubtractDebitOnlyWithDate |  |  |
| 6 | -5 |  |  |

since rows 3 and 4 have dates on B3 and B4, i consider A3 and A4 only, ignoring A2 because B2 is null. since C3 is a debit and C4 is a credit, i evaluate -8 + 3 = -5.

which formula would give me this result on A6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=sum(map(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,lambda(a,b,c,if(a="",,if(isdate(b),ifs(c="C",1,c="D",-1,1,)*a,)))))
```

[image]

Comment: i've edited my question to reflect the real issue. thanks a lot for your answer, i'm already using `=sumif(B:B,"<>",A:A)` to my sheets. sorry for the incomplete problem, but i have two conditionals to be evaluated: one to consider values, other one to decide the sum signal (+ or -)